# Incomplete or no data sometimes - Meteor

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, meteor-blaze, meteor-accounts

I am trying to edit and delete a data in Mongo.Collection. I have a document with a number of fields including an email address.

I check while updating the data if email exists just update the email else first create a user with that email using Accounts.createUser and then update the data. Although the data is being updated successfully in the database but showing it using the helpers is not working properly. I am trying to fill the form with the saved values, either form comes half-filled, or completely-filled(usually in the first edit attempt) or completely empty. I cannot understand the reason behind this beviour.

**The form template**

```
<template name="addUnit">
    <div class="modal fade" id="addUnitModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">{{#if isEdit}}Edit {{else}}Add {{/if}}Unit</h4>
          </div>
            {{#if tenantError}}
                <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">{{tenantError}}</div>
            {{/if}}
            <form class="frmUnit" id="frmUnit">
                <div class="modal-body"> 
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Unit Name" name="unitName" value="{{selectedUnit.unitName}}"/>
                    <input class="form-control" type="number" placeholder="Number of Residents" name="residents" value="{{selectedUnit.residents}}"/>
                    <input class="form-control" type="number" placeholder="Area sqft." name="area" value="{{selectedUnit.area}}"/>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Primary Tenant" name="primaryTenant" value="{{selectedUnit.primaryTenant}}"/>
                    <input class="form-control" type="email" name="tenantEmail" placeholder="Tenant's Email" value="{{selectedUnit.tenantEmail}}"/>
                    <input class="form-control"  type="password" name="tenantPassword" placeholder="Tenant's Password"/>
                </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                {{#if isEdit}}
                    <button type="submit" class="btnEditUnit btn btn-primary">Edit Unit</button>
                {{else}}
                    <button type="submit" class="btnAddUnit btn btn-primary">Add Unit</button>
                {{/if}}

              </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

**Helpers**

```
Template.addUnit.helpers({
    isEdit: function() {
        return Session.get('isEdit');
    },
    tenantError: function(){
        return Session.get('tenantError');
    },
    selectedUnit: function(){
        return Session.get('selectedUnit');
    }
});
```

**Events**

```
Template.addUnit.events({
    "submit .frmUnit": function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var form = event.target;
        if(!Session.get('isEdit')){
            console.log('adding');
            Meteor.call('addUnit', 
                Session.get('selectedBuilding')._id, 
                {
                    unitName: form.unitName.value, 
                    primaryTenant: form.primaryTenant.value, 
                    tenantEmail: form.tenantEmail.value,
                    tenantPassword: form.tenantPassword.value,
                    residents: form.residents.value, 
                    area: form.area.value
                }, function(error, result) {
                    console.log(error, result);
                    if(!error){
                        $('#frmUnit')[0].reset();
                        $('#addUnitModal').modal('hide');
                        Session.set('tenantError', null);
                    }else{
                        Session.set('tenantError', error.reason);
                    }
                });

        }else{
            console.log('editing');
            Meteor.call('editUnit',Session.get('selectedUnit')._id,{
                    unitName: form.unitName.value, 
                    primaryTenant: form.primaryTenant.value, 
                    residents: form.residents.value, 
                    area: form.area.value,
                    tenantEmail: form.tenantEmail.value,
                    tenantPassword: form.tenantPassword.value
                }, function(error, result) {
                    if(!error) {
                        $('#frmUnit')[0].reset();
                        $('#addUnitModal').modal('hide');
                    }else{
                        Session.set('tenantError', error.reason);
                    }
                });
        }
    }
});
```

**Edit unit on the server**

```
editUnit: function(unitId, unit){
    //if the email entered already exists update the email and password
    var updatedTenant = Accounts.findUserByEmail(unit.tenantEmail);
    if(updatedTenant){
      if(unit.tenantPassword && unit.tenantPassword  !== ""){
        Accounts.setPassword(updatedTenant._id, unit.tenantPassword);
      }
      Units.update({_id: unitId}, 
        {
          $set :{
            unitName:unit.unitName, 
            primaryTenant:unit.primaryTenant, 
            residents: unit.residents, 
            area: unit.area,
            tenantEmail: unit.tenantEmail
          }
        });

    }else{
      //if email doesn't exist already, create a new user first
      var newUserId = Accounts.createUser(
      {
        email: unit.tenantEmail, 
        password: unit.tenantPassword, 
        profile:{
          firstname: unit.primaryTenant, 
          lastname:"", 
          phone:"", 
          isTenant:true
        }
      });
      if(newUserId){
         Units.update({_id: unitId}, 
         {
          $set :{
            unitName:unit.unitName, 
            primaryTenant:unit.primaryTenant, 
            residents: unit.residents, 
            area: unit.area,
            tenantEmail:unit.tenantEmail
          }
        });
      }
    }
  },
```

Session.get('selectedUnit') is being set from a different click handler, which displays the form. The value is being set correctly I can see that by logging it to the console.
'isEdit' is also being set from a click handler of a different template.

I have other forms working with the same approach, but they don't have Account creation and validation in them. Is it because of that?

**Edit**

```
Template.owner.events({

"click .editUnit":function(){
        Session.set('isEdit', true);    
        Session.set('selectedUnit', this);
    }
});


{{#each buildingUnits}}
    <tr>
    <td>
        {{unitName}}
    </td>
    <td>
        <span class= "editUnit list-icon glyphicon glyphicon-edit"  data-target="#addUnitModal" data-toggle="modal" aria-hidden="true" style="padding-right: 4px;"></span>
        <span class= "deleteUnit list-icon glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </td>
    </tr>
{{/each}}
```

I have tried to log this onto the console, I am getting the correct result, just after the two lines I tried to get the session back using Session.get('selectedUnit') and tried logging it to console, this also gives me the correct result, which means session is being successfully set.

Comment: Can we see some code for where you set selectedUnit?